# Integrating uber api phonegap

Tags: uber-api

Please excuse my lack of technical knowledge i'm no developer or software engineer.

I have hired a team to develop an app using Phonegap. Is it possible to integrate Uber into the existing app?

Any advise would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes! As long as your app has a working [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client that is able to make HTTP requests to the [Uber API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/api-overview) RESTful HTTP server and receive HTTP responses.